# Using the #[constant] macro in anchor depending on feature flag

Tags: anchor, idl, anchor-program-idl

Does anyone know if there is a method to produce an IDL that has different constants depending on the feature flag?

I have tried variations of

```
#[cfg(not(feature = "mainnet"))]
#[constant]
pub const IMP_CONST: USIZE = 1

#[cfg(feature = "mainnet")]
#[constant]
pub const IMP_CONST: USIZE = 2
```

and defining at module level

```
#[cfg(not(feature = "mainnet"))]
pub mod devnet_constants;

#[cfg(not(feature = "mainnet"))]
pub use devnet_constants::*;


#[cfg(feature = "mainnet")]
pub mod mainnet_constants;

#[cfg(feature = "mainnet"))]
pub use mainnet_constants::*;
```

Although both versions of the constants appear in the outputted IDL after `anchor build -- --features "mainnet"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told in the anchor discord that

> It's because currently the idl parse directly the .rs file. You need
> to wait the V2 of idl generation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any such method and it probably doesn't exist. The generator simply parses `all` the tokens in the source code pre-build using syn and generates the IDL from that; it doesn't take into account stuff like conditional compilation that might change the build.